# Add (+) 1 to each row that has 0 in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a *dataframe* that looks like this.

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "    REF_CNT.x ALT_CNT.x REF_CNT.y ALT_CNT.y
1         397         0       574         2
2         417         2       219         0
3         537         2        31         0
4         117         5       154         0
5          76         2        52         0
6         238         0       102         2
7         265         0       108         2
8         177         6       156         6
9         407         0       359         4
10        770         3        64         0", header = TRUE)
```

How do I add 1 to each row if there is 0 in the row?

Comment: would be easier if you provided expected output, not entirely clear to me what you want

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. When you posted here, you submitted content to the site under a CC-BY-SA license and transferred ownership to the site. Please don't vandalize content which is no longer (only) yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add 1 to the whole row that contains 0, then the following could help:

```
df[apply(df,1,function(v) prod(v) ==0),] <- df[apply(df,1,function(v) prod(v) ==0),]+1
```

A more efficient way is to use `rowSum`, i.e.:

```
df[rowSums(df==0)>0,] <- df[rowSums(df==0)>0,]+1
```

Comment: Rather than `apply`ing `prod`, a more common method (and more efficient) would be `rowSums(df == 0, na.rm = TRUE) > 0`

Comment: Thanks for point that out! It is updated in my solution as well @Gregor